# eclipse не могу добавить пакет классов

Tags: java, eclipse, импорт

Здравствуйте. Как добавить пакеты в проект Eclipse? Есть каталог src. В него залил папку пакетов библиотеки. Но из другого пакета, в этой же папки src, не виден первый пакет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложи  скрин как ты папку залил

Comment: Выложил, посмотрите в описаниии вопроса

Comment: Библиотеку обычно как jar файл подключают.

Comment: И что. Мне нужно папкой. Или это нельзя никак сделать? Или мне собирать библиотеку jar самому с нужной папки?

Comment: В тексте ты написал, что не видно `src/org/net/file.java`, а на скрине, что не видно `src/com/test/file.java`.

Comment: Выложи код, как ты импортируешь класс.

Comment: `import com.*;` не видит никак. YНо я никак не импортирую. Обычно при использовании неизвестных классов, eclipse сам предлагает мне импортировать. Но в данном случае он не видит пакетов нужных. То есть проблема не в импорте а в подключении класссов

Comment: В папке com нужно класса нет, так что импортируешь неправильно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что eclipse не видит каким то образом пакеты com, как показано на рисунке. И при создании выдуманного тестового класса, тоже не видит. Проблема не в импорте

Comment: Добавил ещё скрин проблемы

Comment: Eclipse думает, что это не пакеты, а простые папки. Выдели package, нажми правую клавишу мыши и выбери `build path->use as source folder`

Comment: Выложи код `Testerfwrg.java`

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. Нужно делать `build path->use as source folder` и в исходниках пакетов, смотреть `package`

Comment: В смысле смотреть `package`? Добавь ответ на вопрос

Comment: [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117237/why-is-my-eclipse-java-package-being-treated-as-a-folder) советовали можно выполнить `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Ты используешь Maven?

Comment: Спасибо. Можете ответить на мой вопрос таким ответом. >Что нужно сделать 1. Создать соус фолде, 2. залить туда пакеты. если все пакеты в каталоге com, то папку `com` скидываете в соусную папку (source folder)<. и я отмечу вопрос как решенный

Comment: У вас папка `com` и так была в папке `src`.

Comment: >У вас папка com и так была в папке src. Странно, как я мог не заметить, куда я клал папку. Возможно она у меня и не там лежала, а где-то в диске C. Нужно проверить

Comment: Ты же это в вопросе написал

Comment: Откуда ты знаешь? А где я?

Comment: > Есть каталог src. В него залил папку пакетов библиотеки.